# Microsoft Monitoring Agent APM service is inaccessible. Please check that it is not in a disabled state

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, application-pools

We encountered an issue where the agent (referred to as the Microsoft Monitoring Agent) in the IIS server - however,the IIS Application Pools began to cause high CPU usage the application server without a reason.

> What are fixes that I can apply to avoid this issue further ?

### Event Log

```
Microsoft Monitoring Agent APM service is inaccessible. Please check that it is not in a disabled state. 

System information:
Agent version: 8.0.10918.0
Windows version: 2.6.3.3.400.0.9.0;
.NET Framework: v4.0.30319
Process ID: 3276; Instance ID: 0;
InstanceName: w3wp.exe [x86];
Application Pool: Application Pool Name.
```

---

```
 Performance counters corrupted. 

System information:
Agent version: 8.0.10918.0
Windows version: 2.6.3.3.400.0.9.0;
.NET Framework: v4.0.30319
Process ID: 3276; Instance ID: 0;
InstanceName: w3wp.exe [x86];
Application Pool: Application Pool Name.
```